# App crashes while accessing data from firebase and setting it to a variable

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Consider the following code here I am accessing data from the firebase database and updating the variable `id` .But when I try to run the app it is crashing displaying the message which I have attached below.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;

LocationManager locationManager;

LocationListener locationListener;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
DatabaseReference mData;
DatabaseReference mId;
static int id = 1;


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

            Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            centerMapOnLocation(lastKnownLocation, "Your location");

        }


    }

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    final String uid = mAuth.getUid();
    mData = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(uid).child(String.valueOf(id));
    mId = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    mId.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            updateid(dataSnapshot,uid);
           // id = Integer.parseInt(dataSnapshot.child("id").getValue(String.class));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
LatLng userLocation;
public void centerMapOnLocation(Location location, String title) {
    if(location!= null){
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
       userLocation = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    }



    mMap.clear();

    if (title != "Your location") {

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title(title));

    }

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLocation, 10));

}

@Override
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {

    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
    String address="";

    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude,latLng.longitude,1);



        if (addresses != null &&addresses.size() != 0)
        {
            if(addresses.get(0).getSubThoroughfare() != null)
            {
                if(addresses.get(0).getThoroughfare()!=null)
                {
                    address+=addresses.get(0).getSubThoroughfare();

                }

                address+=addresses.get(0).getThoroughfare();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(address == "")
    {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ",Locale.ENGLISH);
        address=dateFormat.format(new Date());
    }

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(address));


   // DatabaseReference ref = mData.child(mAuth.getUid());
    mData.child("lat").setValue(latLng.latitude);
    mData.child("long").setValue(latLng.longitude);

    id++;
    mId.child("Id").setValue(id);



    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

private void updateid(DataSnapshot data,String uid) {
  // data.child(uid).getValue(User.class).getName();

    User u = new User();
    for(DataSnapshot ds : data.getChildren()) {

        u.setId(ds.child(uid).getValue(User.class).getId());

    }
    id = u.getId(); 

}

/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            if(location!= null){
                double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                double longitude = location.getLongitude();
              //  userLocation = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                centerMapOnLocation(location, "Your location");
            }



        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

        }
    };
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

    } else {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

            Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            centerMapOnLocation(lastKnownLocation, "Your location");

        } else {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);

        }


    }
}
```

My `User` class is as follows

```
public class User {
private String name;
private String phone;
private  String email;
private  String password;
int id;


public User() {

}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

}

Error Log message is given as

```
Process: com.example.ashwanths.helpwithfood, PID: 32645
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.example.ashwanths.helpwithfood.User.getId()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.ashwanths.helpwithfood.MapsActivity.updateid(MapsActivity.java:174)
    at com.example.ashwanths.helpwithfood.MapsActivity.access$000(MapsActivity.java:38)
    at com.example.ashwanths.helpwithfood.MapsActivity$1.onDataChange(MapsActivity.java:87)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzegf.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeia.zzbyc(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeig.run(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

The output That I want is that if I add a marker in the map then Id value in firebase database should be automatically incremented

[image: Screen shot of my database]

Comment: show the database please

Comment: I attached my database @PeterHaddad

Comment: `ds.child(uid).getValue(User.class)` should *return* a User. There's no reason to make your own and just set the ID. Also `ID:2` is in the wrong spot of your database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.example.ashwanths.helpwithfood.User.getId()' on a null object reference
```

Because you are calling `getId()` method on a reference which has the value of `null`.

As i see in you database, the following line of code:

```
ds.child(uid).getValue(User.class);
```

Already returns a `User` class object. There is no need to create another `User` class object. If you do, all the fields inside that object will also have the value of `null`.

The field `Id: 2` should not be placed beneath `Users` node. All the childrens beneath this node should be of the same type, which is of type `User` class not of type `Integer` or `Long`. To solve this, move that field in another spot of yopur database.

If that `id` can be modified my concurent users, I also recommend you use [Firebase Transactios](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) to have accurate data in your database.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this. Your database reference is getting one single user in your database:

```
mData = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(uid)
```

But when you call the `updateid()` method your interating through the attributes of the user:

```
private void updateid(DataSnapshot data,String uid) {
  // data.child(uid).getValue(User.class).getName();

    User u = new User();
    for(DataSnapshot ds : data.getChildren()) {

        u.setId(ds.child(uid).getValue(User.class).getId());

    }
    id = u.getId(); 

}
```

This for example `ds.child(uid)` won't work, and then you try to convert it to a User, which is something this datasnapshot isn't. When firebase does `getValue(User.class)` it will return null and that's why you're getting NPE here.

The variable `data` already has a user (as a Datasnapshot). So you should simply do:

```
private void updateid(DataSnapshot data,String uid) {
   data.getRef().child("id").setValueAsyn(newID);

}
```

EDIT:

If you want to get the user object, do it like this:

```
private void updateid(DataSnapshot data,String uid) {
      Integer retrievedID = data.getValue(Integer.class);
      if(retrievedID!=null){
       id = retrievedID;
       }

    }
```

Comment: No actually what I wanted is I want to read the value of Id from the database and increment it in android and then again update it.The incrementing part rest are working fine the thing is I am not able to retrieve the Id from the database using the right path.Can you specify the path  to retrieve it. Another point is that I am using another database instance mId for retrieving the id.

Comment: Actually 0 is being stored in id and the value of id is not incrementing on long click.

Comment: Not I want to get the Id value 2 to be stored in the variable id.

Comment: aw, now I see what th problem was. The updateid method is called in the mId node, ok. I think now it should work.I've edited the method again

Comment: Any luck here??

Comment: great to know :)